# Golang - Dropbox webhook signature validation hmac

Tags: go, dropbox-api, hmac, sha256, webhooks

I am writing a program that needs to use Dropbox's webhooks. I haven't been able to find any Go implementation already in place, so I've decided to write mine. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

I think the issue here is with **hmac**, as I am most probably doing something wrong, but I just can't seem to understand where exactly the issue here. Any idea?

The following is what I have:

```
package dboxwebhook

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type Signature struct {
    AppSecret []byte
    Signature []byte
}

func (w *Signature) Check(reqBody io.ReadCloser) error {

    if bytes.Compare(w.Signature, nil) == 0 {
        return errors.New("DropBox signature doesnt exist")
    }

    // building HMAC key (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/hmac/)
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, w.AppSecret)
    requestBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reqBody)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    mac.Write(requestBody)
    expectedMac := mac.Sum(nil)

    log.Println(w.AppSecret)
    log.Println(expectedMac)
    log.Println(w.Signature)

    // compare if it corresponds with the signature sent by DropBox
    comparison := hmac.Equal(w.Signature, expectedMac)

    if !comparison {
        return errors.New("Signature Check unsuccessful")
    }

    return nil

}
```

To test this, the only way I know is to use [this Python script](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox_hook) from Dropbox.

Comment: Have you tried logging the request body to verify it matches the data sent?

Comment: I assume what you're seeing is "Signature Check unsuccessful"? Another random guess: the signature in the header will be hex encoded, so make sure wherever you parse that, you're doing it properly. This question would be more answerable if you gave example inputs and the hash you're computing, since the error could be in lots of places.

Comment: `w.Signature` is the hex encoded key sent by DropBox. On my side, according to DropBox's documentation, I am supposed to encode the request body being sent, using my *secret* string as the key. Then I need to compare the two values and make sure they are the same. But, at the moment, they aren't.

Comment: If the signature you're comparing to is hex encoded, then you need to hex encode the signature you compute also. It doesn't look like you're doing that.

Comment: isn't `expectedMac` hex-encoded? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `expectedMac` is of type `[]byte`. https://golang.org/src/crypto/hmac/hmac.go?s=1395:1434#L53

Comment: it seems likely that you have a string representation of hex characters stored in `w.Signature`, since dropbox is sending you hex-encoded bytes over the wire as a string most likely (how you handle this is not provided in your question so i'm just guessing). can you post some more of your code?

Answer (score 5):

The Dropbox signature is sent as string in the HTTP header `X-Dropbox-Signature`.

So as to use it with `hmac.Equal`, you need to decode the hex string representation to a slice of byte first using package [encoding/hex](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/).

```
    import "encoding/hex"

    [...]
    hexSignature, err := hex.DecodeString(w.Signature)
    [...]
```

Then you can use the hex bytes in the comparison

```
    [...]
    // compare if it corresponds with the signature sent by DropBox
    comparison := hmac.Equal(hexSignature, expectedMac)
    [...]
```